# Can we use socket.io with ejs(embedded javascript) instead of html page in Node JS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, ejs

On client side in browser as ejs page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js">
</script>
<script>
var socket = io()
socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
})
</script>
```

On server side in Node Js:

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected')
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected')
    })
io.emit('message', json);
})
```

I'm not getting 'a user connected' log in Node Js console. Because **var socket = io()** is **not working** or what is the problem i don't know. Can i use **socket.io in .ejs** page? I need ejs and i also need socket.io in my application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should connect it to your server and port no. `var socket = io('localhost:port')`, refer http://www.sachinsharma.com/2012/07/simple-application-using-expressjs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked fine for me.

**Server-side**

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = require('express')();
var server      = require('http').createServer(app);
var io          = require('socket.io')(server);
var ejs         = require('ejs');


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
      });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log('app running');
});
```

And here is the index.ejs code

**client-side**

```
        <form action="">
                <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
           $(function () {
                var socket = io();
                $('form').submit(function(){
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Try to explain a little bit more what you are doing.